# summarize column with data.table using rlang

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, rlang

I'm new in `data.table`
How to make the same thing with `data.table` using `rlang`?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

gr <- "Species"
col <- "Petal.Length"

iris %>% 
  group_by(!!rlang::sym(gr)) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(!!rlang::sym(col)),sum)

iris1 <- iris 
setDT(iris1)
iris1[,sum(!!rlang::sym(col)),by=!!rlang::sym(gr)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `get`:

```
iris1[, sum(get(col)), by = get(gr)]
```

As @mmn pointed out, you can also skip `get` in the `by` argument.

Comment: would like to add that `by` accepts `character`, so you dont need `get` in `by`.

Comment: You're right, however I normally use `get` or `mget` even in `by` as it helps distinguishing between referring to actual column name, function argument, etc.

Comment: Good point, just wanted to add this option as an additional possibility